# How to pass a value from mysql to c# variable and keep two decimal places

Tags: c#, mysql, floating-point, formatting, double

I'm a novice in C# and I couldn't find a answer for this...

I have a select inside my application where I try to get a double value and pass it to a variable so I can display it.

The double value is actually the balance a user have in its card.

The point is althought the value in the database is for example 42.00 when it is passed to my variable its displayed as 42.0 (without the second decimal place)

What can I do so I dont loose the second decimal place?

Thank you!

Comment: `"its displayed as 42.0"` - How are you displaying it?  Can you specify a numeric format string when you do?

Comment: Double does not store insignificant digits FYI.  Also, when dealing with money, you should really be using `decimal`

Comment: No one can tell you what is wrong with your code if you dont show us the code.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework or Ado.Net ?

Comment: Some have voted to close this because it's not about programming. With respect, I disagree. It's a simple question.

Answer (score 1):

`double` items have, internally, a data representation that doesn't limit, or specify, the number of decimal places.  `42.`, `42.0`, and `42.00` are the same number internally.  That's true in MySQL, and inside your C# program, and elsewhere.

The number of decimal places used to display a `double` is part of rendering it: of turning it into a text string to show a user.

To render a `double` data item with two decimal places, you need an appropriate [custom numeric format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings). That is `"0.00"`.

```
  double foobar = 42.424242
  string str = foobar.ToString("0.00");    // gets 42.42
  foobar = -42.424242
  str = foobar.ToString("0.00");           // gets -42.42
  foobar = -0.424242
  str = foobar.ToString("0.00");           // gets -0.42
```

So, use `.ToString("0.00")` to render your numbers and you'll meet your goal.

You can also use the `"C"` (currency) format string. That will use your locale's currency rendering rules.  In USA it looks like this.

```
  str = foobar.ToString("C");           // gets ($0.42)
```

Others have mentioned that a decimal data type might be more appropriate for money. That's true. But you'll still have to render it correctly.